# os.system opens just the code

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to run a python program inside of another python program. 
and those two programs run in a thread. 
Now, I don't know why, but when I try these two lines on my PC it opens the program and runs it, however on my laptop, it just opens a weird window with just the code itself and does not run the code.

```
import os
os.system("theName.py")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have a defined interpreter for `.py` files on your laptop - you didn't mention what OS you're using, but under the assumption it's Windows you may want to install [`Python Launcher for Windows`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) on your laptop.

Comment: oh, that's why I got -1? sorry for that. :)

Comment: You didn't get it from me, but in all fairness this is a pretty poor quality question.

Comment: how can I make it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) on a `.py` file does the same thing as executing the file directly at the command line. Depending on your platform and your settings, and whether the file has the exec bit set, and whether it starts with a proper shebang line, that could do any of the following:

- Run the script.
- Open the script in whatever default editor is set for `.py` files.
- Try to run the script with the wrong Python version.
- Try to run your script as if it were shell code instead of Python code, which fails with a syntax error unless you’re very unlucky.
- Fail with an error about not knowing how to execute this kind of file.
- Fail with an error about the file not being executable.

You’re probably getting the second one on your laptop—but any of them are possible, and only one of them is what you actually want.

As the docs for `os.system` say, you almost always want to use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module instead of `os.system`. In this case, what you probably want is something like:

```
subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'script.py'], check=True)
```

That means to run `script.py` [using the same Python interpreter being used to run the current script](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable), let input and output pass through (just like `system` does), and check and raise an exception if it exits with an exception or other failure instead of ignoring the error. That may not be exactly what you want; in that case, read the `subprocess` docs (including [the recipes for replacing older functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module)) for how to do what you want instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing a system command, which depends on the configuration of the OS. There is a good chance that on the laptop, when you double click on a python file it is edited.

You should at least tell it to open `python` program, with the file as an argument. For example something like:

```
os.system("<python path>/python.exe  theName.py")
```